# Ohio LinuxFest 2010

Tags: discussion

Will anyone be attending [Ohio LinuxFest](http://www.ohiolinux.org/) this year?  I plan to attend and am trying to promote SF there.

It looks like it's [too late](http://ohiolinux.org/sponsorship.html) to run a booth, but if there's enough interest this year I'd be willing to organize running a booth next year.

It is one of the largest Linux conferences in North America.  From the [about page](http://www.ohiolinux.org/about.html):

> The Ohio LinuxFest welcomes people from all 50 states and international participants. We've had participants from Canada, England, Argentina, Brazil, and Australia in years past.

Answer (score 3):

I'll be there on Saturday for sure, and possibly Friday. I'd be into helping out w/ a booth for next year's show, as well.

Comment: Very cool.  We'll definitely have to meet up!

Comment: I'll be the guy in the black Server Fault t-shirt... >smile<  Yeah-- I look forward to meeting you. (I don't actually look like a unicorn. It occurs to me that my real picture hasn't been on the site since April. I should probably remedy that sometime.)